# jQuery - Poner como atributo alt el titulo de una imagen

Tags: jquery

Quiero que las imagenes de una página me pongan como atributo alt de todas ellas el mismo texto que tienen para el atributo title. ¿Se haría así?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($("img"), function(index, element) {
     $(element).attr("alt", $(element).title());
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con tu código sería así:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($("img"), function(index, element) {
     $(element).attr("alt", $(element).attr("title"));
  });
});
</script>
```

Sin embargo yo prefiero utilizar el siguiente fragmento ya que resulta más claro y ahorras un poco de código.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").each(function() {
     $(this).attr("alt", $(this).attr("title"));
  });
});
</script>
```

Adjunto un ejemplo práctico:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("alt", $(this).attr("title"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" title="title 1">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" title="title 2">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" title="title 3">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" title="title 4">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" title="title 5">
```

Comment: Gracias, me deberia de funcionar pero o se porque en prestashop no me lo hace.

Comment: ¿como podria hacerlo para que si encuentra una imagen que su src sea x url me ponga el titulo que yo diga? gracias.

Comment: dentro del `each` podrias poner un `if($(this).attr('src') == "tu url") { //acción }`

Comment: Eso pondrá el mismo alt que el título para todas las imágenes que estén dentro del elemento con id "subcategories" y que tengan de src "URL"

Comment: tenia un fallo yo, ya esta! gracias